# Instantiated a SQLAlchemy Declarative mapped class requires the autogenerated and relationship attributes to be set

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, argument-error

I have a one-many table relationship between Company and Element and think I have defined them correctly

```
class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    stype: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10))
    elements: Mapped[List["Element"]] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Company(name={self.name!r})>"


class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = "element"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    element: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
    company: Mapped["Company"] = relationship(back_populates="elements")
```

However, when I attempt to instantiate the class with

```
company = Company(name=df['name'][index], url=df['url'][index], stype=df['stype'][index])
```

I get the interpreter complaining that I am missing the company and id arguments. Its my understanding that neither needs to be explicitly defined

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1500, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "F:\Onedrive\8. Coding\Python\pvp\database\model.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Onedrive\8. Coding\Python\pvp\database\model.py", line 63, in main
    insert_companies()
  File "F:\Onedrive\8. Coding\Python\pvp\database\model.py", line 55, in insert_companies
    company = Company(name=df['name'][index], url=df['url'][index], stype=df['stype'][index])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'id' and 'elements'
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Complete code (which I should have just started with....)

```
from typing import List

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column, String, Float, Integer,
    ForeignKey
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://dkhokhar:1286Qyts@gd2-dbmain-service:3306/pvp")
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    stype: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10))
    elements: Mapped[List["Element"]] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Company(name={self.name!r})>"


class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = "element"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    element: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
    company: Mapped["Company"] = relationship(back_populates="elements")


class ItemPrice(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item_price"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    price: Mapped[float]
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))


def insert_companies():
    print("Reading csv: pvp_init.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv("../data/pvp_dbinit.csv")
    print("Populating Company table..")
    for index in df.index:
        # [''] = column [index] = row for 2d array
        print(f"{df['name'][index]} {df['url'][index]} {df['stype'][index]}")

        company = Company(name=df['name'][index], url=df['url'][index], stype=df['stype'][index])
        with session_factory.begin() as sess:
            sess.merge(company)


def main():
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn)
    insert_companies()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So I did forget to mention that I can set init=False on the auto-gen argument but this was not expressed in any of the documentation I read. If that is a solution for the id I am still unsure of the syntax to do this for the relationship argument.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `class Base` please? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I do not have a __init__ set in either the base or sub class

Comment: yes I am using dataclass mappings. Sorry forgot to put the Base class in. Added to top of original question

Comment: Maybe add `init=False` to `elements`: `elements: Mapped[List["Element"]] = relationship(init=False)`

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure what the syntax was. OK that works. The documentation flips between DeclarativeBase and MappedAsDataclass so I just need to take notice of which is for which. Thank-you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html#attribute-configuration):

> **init**, as in mapped_column.init, relationship.init, if False indicates the field should not be part of the **init**() method

You should set `init=False` to all fields that are not be a part of the constructor:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False)  # <- HERE
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    stype: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10))
    elements: Mapped[List["Element"]] = relationship(init=False)  # <- HERE

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Company(name={self.name!r})>"
```

Edit: you can also remove `MappedAsDataclass` from `Base` class declaration if it's not necessary to use `dataclass`:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    stype: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10))
    elements: Mapped[List["Element"]] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Company(name={self.name!r})>"
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb. Yes. OP can also remove `MappedAsDataclass` mixin from `Base` class declaration. I updated my answer according your comment.